# I could not able to open config.xml in android app

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I am newbie to android hybrid app development using (javascript+phonegap ) and I have few queries.

1. I could not able to open the config.xml file.
2. How to ensure only fully trusted domains on included in the  setting within the config.xml file.

Thanks,
Senthil

Comment: well...you can view config.xml located in www folder,or drag xml file to explorer.Hope it'll work